How to read in a (compressed) .gdb using R and or SF Package?
I want to open a GDB (A directory that ends with ".gdb") in R. I am assuming that some sublayers or the whole GDB is compressed, though i do not know how to confirm this. I have tried st_read() of the sf Package, but some layers are read without any features and i get an error message:
> st_layers("C:/path/to/name.gdb")
Driver: OpenFileGDB 
Available layers:
                     layer_name                 geometry_type features fields              crs_name
1                           WSG                 Multi Polygon        0      0 ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N
2                          HQSG                 Multi Polygon        0      0 ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N
3            Boden_natur_kultur                 Multi Polygon     2220     16 ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N
4                            BR                 Multi Polygon      212     19 ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N
5                           WEA                         Point      881     17 ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N
6               Fliessgewaesser 3D Measured Multi Line String   236407     18 ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N
7                Standgewaesser     3D Measured Multi Polygon    15905     17 ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N
8        Grundwasserflurabstand                 Multi Polygon    26604     15 ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N
9                    Georisiken                 Multi Polygon      241     14 ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N
10          nat_Waldentwicklung     3D Measured Multi Polygon     7996     18 ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N
11           Kulturlandschaften                 Multi Polygon       78     17 ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N
12 Boden_grundwasserbeeinflusst                 Multi Polygon    31522     17 ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N
13  Boden_stauwasserbeeinflusst                 Multi Polygon    13837     17 ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N
14                 Biogasanlage                         Point      150     16 ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N

> read_sf("C:/path/to/name.gdb",
+         "WSG")
Simple feature collection with 0 features and 0 fields
Bounding box:  xmin: NA ymin: NA xmax: NA ymax: NA
Projected CRS: ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N
# A tibble: 0 × 1
# ℹ 1 variable: SHAPE <GEOMETRY [m]>
Warnmeldung:
In CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  :
  GDAL Error 1: Error occurred in ../../../../gdal-3.8.4/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/openfilegdb/filegdbtable.cpp at line 1007

I managed to convert the GDB into a GeoPackage using the following ogr command line command in the OSGeoW Shell:
ogr2ogr  -f GPKG "C:/path/to/file/name_of_file.gpkg" "C:/path/to/file/name_of_file.gdb" --config OGR_SKIP OpenFileGDB

The resulting GeoPackage has a Layer WSG with the correct number of features.
Without the last argument --config OGR_SKIP OpenFileGDB it produces the empty layers again. I am assuming it forces to use the ESRI Driver that i received by installing QGIS via the OSGeo4W installer.
Nonethelesse, is there an option to read in such GDBs into R withouth the use of ogr2ogr or other outside R tools?
A solution where i call this from within R would be much appreciated too.

Have you tried using the options argument in read_sf() to pass --config OGR_SKIP OpenFileGDB to GDAL?

terra::vect, proxy = TRUE,  with sql dialect will work. If you point to your data, we can consider better.

@Coy, i will look into that, but st_drivers shows me that only the OpenFileGDB Driver ist present, not the FileGDB one. Also, including the options gives me a warning
1: In CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  :
GDAL Message 6: open option '--config OGR_SKIP OpenFileGDB' is not formatted with the key=value format.
To Chris Sadly, i cant publish the data and do not know how subdivide the dataset, so the error persist

Neither of the hinted solutions works.
